# DRM playready license acquisition

Tags: drm, playready

i'm implementing a DRM server, so far HLS is working great but i have a problem with the playready key encryption, i know that i need to use the public key and License Nonce(IV) from the client request but i couldn't find the algorithm to encrypt it.

example from [Microsoft playReady test server](http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/doc/slee/)

client requst:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <AcquireLicense xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols">
      <challenge>
        <Challenge xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols/messages">
          <LA xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols" Id="SignedData" xml:space="preserve">
            <Version>1</Version>
            <ContentHeader>
              <WRMHEADER xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader" version="4.0.0.0">
                <DATA>
         <PROTECTINFO>
          <KEYLEN>16</KEYLEN>
          <ALGID>AESCTR</ALGID>
         </PROTECTINFO>
         <KID>7987aj+eE0uBlXi0N73AQw==</KID>
         <CHECKSUM>s1zZSs3Wwow=</CHECKSUM>
         <CUSTOMATTRIBUTES>
          <IIS_DRM_VERSION>7.1.1064.0</IIS_DRM_VERSION>
         </CUSTOMATTRIBUTES>
         <LA_URL>http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx</LA_URL>
         <DS_ID>AH+03juKbUGbHl1V/QIwRA==</DS_ID>
        </DATA>
              </WRMHEADER>
            </ContentHeader>
            <CLIENTINFO>
              <CLIENTVERSION>2.0.0.1446</CLIENTVERSION>
            </CLIENTINFO>
            <RevocationLists>
              <RevListInfo>
                <ListID>ioydTlK2p0WXkWklprR5Hw==</ListID>
                <Version>11</Version>
              </RevListInfo>
              <RevListInfo>
                <ListID>gC4IKKPHsUCCVhnlttibJw==</ListID>
                <Version>11</Version>
              </RevListInfo>
              <RevListInfo>
                <ListID>BOZ1zT1UnEqfCf5tJOi/kA==</ListID>
                <Version>12</Version>
              </RevListInfo>
              <RevListInfo>
                <ListID>Ef/RUojT3U6Ct2jqTCChbA==</ListID>
                <Version>34</Version>
              </RevListInfo>
            </RevocationLists>
            <LicenseNonce>e7NgfwBi1xX/egdgV9BrWQ==</LicenseNonce>
            <EncryptedData xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
              <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
              <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                  <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols#ecc256" />
                  <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <KeyName>WMRMServer</KeyName>
                  </KeyInfo>
                  <CipherData>
                    <CipherValue>W13Rs+iFyn5Qgh8iAduenxsRw3w2mOTNhfOPI6Fwv5kIn93cCauDFJexka6jtQHJ+by8wyTv4u7RofeZW9G8NakvV0JpGg7d5rEg1q1XMwy267Hecnch75FKEPSiydx2NU83IambHenRhJJ5gg3/u1aVpaXsCVtnQsv5pt5L+JM=</CipherValue>
                  </CipherData>
                </EncryptedKey>
              </KeyInfo>
              <CipherData>
                <CipherValue>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</CipherValue>
              </CipherData>
            </EncryptedData>
          </LA>
          <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols#ecdsa-sha256" />
              <Reference URI="#SignedData">
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>Y6z9FSz2qWpvIN823wrK13in0TnWGoAcPCKw9KlWZPk=</DigestValue>
              </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>u45hKzad6Wir2SLSY7WTkTxpziPY2w5WTiLbNSb0RyciFV8Xm2aFyLbOCpMW33ZYubN59lsaZy8fAjUsr7ManA==</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
              <KeyValue>
                <ECCKeyValue>
                  <PublicKey>2sumijs/TOhMhxwvkmjp4nXwJku8UXFHU+oY4fg+sRTp/pM7O3/w4k4QXAAn69pHahdLN+6OGpnQfwTv4xzGCQ==</PublicKey>
                </ECCKeyValue>
              </KeyValue>
            </KeyInfo>
          </Signature>
        </Challenge>
      </challenge>
    </AcquireLicense>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

server response:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <AcquireLicenseResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols">
   <AcquireLicenseResult>
    <Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols/messages">
     <LicenseResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/protocols">
      <Version>1</Version>
      <Licenses>
       <License>WE1SAAAAAAN7s2B/AGLXFf96B2BX0GtZAAMAAQAAAVAAAgAEAAAACAADAAIAAAAyAAAADQAAAAoAAQABADIAAAAMAAAAIgABADQAAAAKAJYAAAAzAAAACgABAAMACQAAAPIAAQAKAAAAnu/fO2o/nhNLgZV4tDe9wEMAAQADAIDB6u6Ltq5a8s2SvNkd4kAVzxDnlUysqzX6k5epsJ4iNaZaFyLTtpgVjTRQP2lgDeJaJSIObuf2yd2Qd1tWIQDk4gXxCbUPL8NJgdvl6d4z2xBIvJq4Ol3KDiHgkYn6mYEyniIm+2IWZUrUWsKo6Z2brnsoe3GoYoNmXkJ5+kyMOgAAACoAAABMAAEAQDrjNbZngMLUdzVuWakTkwXziavX6rZhzIaQJYQOWLtJSqiFpiWTutb777SRP48Zvx2FMpyqhGdjn53dLmsiRDYAAQALAAAAHAABABB8/phYFmuGw7Y3HoQs0swN</License>
      </Licenses>
      <Acknowledgement>
       <TransactionID>5c062475-4b2c-48e6-9b0b-54fce5b2b770</TransactionID>
      </Acknowledgement>
     </LicenseResponse>
    </Response>
   </AcquireLicenseResult>
  </AcquireLicenseResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

how do i create the License from the client request and my 16 byte key?

Comment: What do you mean by implementing PlayReady license server? You are not supposed to "implement it". That is not how it works. You are supposed to deploy Microsoft PlayReady Server product and use it. It looks like you are trying to create PlayReady service without paying MS the fee. It will not work because without MS, your service will not be trusted by clients and they will refuse messages from your service.

Comment: Microsoft is just an example,  there are other servers like that,
and  i don't think this algorithm is confidential, maybe i'm wrong

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Microsoft is just an example". There are third party providers of PlayReady service but those providers didn't roll out their own stuff. They paid Microsoft to use PlayReady Server SDK and to get certificate required for their services to be trusted by clients.